# In what order will enemies be attacked if the selected target dies mid-turn?

Tags: bravely-second

In Bravely Second: End Layer, in what order will characters attack enemies if the initial target of their attack becomes untargetable mid-turn (ie from dying)?

For example, suppose you are in a battle against enemies A, B, C, and D (in that order on the enemy roster list). You then command all of your party to attack enemy A. After a hit from your first party member, enemy A dies. However, there are still other attack commands from your other party members ready to go. Which of enemies B, C, and D will be selected as the target for those party members' attacks?

I would have assumed that the next enemy in the enemy roster (enemy B in the above example) would be selected as the target, but it doesn't appear to be the case. In fact, from my observations it looks like it is random - but I cannot be sure.

Is there a set order for which enemy would be selected? Or is it random? I would really like to know this since often there are situations where one enemy has a buff such as Reflect or Wall, and having the game choose to attack them without me specifically wanting to attack them would be detrimental.

Comment: I would go with Seiyria's answer (this applies to a lot of RPGs), but one thing to keep in mind, if you keep track your character's speeds, you can usually figure out which order they will attack in.  Keep that in mind when you create a strategy for longer battles.  To give an example, in Bravely Default, you can use a stillness strategy on any boss that basically makes it so you make the slowest character use stillness every 2 turns to negate all damage, while the other 3 faster characters attack before the stillness is cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chosen enemy is completely random. If you anticipate killing an enemy with your attack, then spread them out more instead of piling them all on one target.

Comment: Hmm... After more playing of the game this was the only conclusion I could come to as well. Just wondering, do you have a source for this information or did you infer it?

Comment: The only source I have is playing the game and doing lots of auto battle. One of my command sets is 4x attack on everyone, and when grinding in an area, I repeatedly kill and choose a random enemy after (especially visible when fighting the same enemy groups).